# How to set sys.modules["m"]=<current module>

Tags: python

I have this structure:

```
merged.py:
  everything

main.py:
  import merged
  sys.modules['othermodule'] = merged
  othermodule.f()
```

If I merged this into single file `main.py`, is there any way to tell `othermodule` resolve to `main` while inside of `main.py`?

This situation happens when using [amalgamate](https://github.com/xonsh/amalgamate) package to concat everything into single file, but the result is two files with structure like above, and I'm trying to get it down to one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sys.modules['othermodule'] = sys.modules[__name__]
```

Gets the current module you are in and sets as othermodule.
Now you can:

```
import othermodule
othermodule.f()
```

If you prefer to assign module to variable you can simply:

```
othermodule = sys.modules[__name__]
othermodule.f()
```

Comment: that doesn't help me set `sys.modules` to the current module

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. Edited.